# How to check size of svg image?

Tags: javascript, svg

I store some image in a JS variable:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAAsUlEQVR4nO3BAQEAAACCIP+vbkhAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB8GXHmAAFMgHIEAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

But even if I store an empty image it has some value like previous image. Is it possible to define is this image empty or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does this question have the SVG tag?  The image is a PNG, not an SVG.

Answer (score 0):

The base64 string is an encoded PNG image. You need to decode it first. There is a library for JavaScript that does this: https://github.com/arian/pngjs

You can then use `png.getWidth();` and `png.getHeight();` to get the height and width.